# select rows based on next row in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have a table like this :

```
Type | Time
1    | 234234
2    | 234235
1    | 234238
3    | 234239
4    | 234240
1    | 234242
2    | 234245
```

I want to count number of all those rows where `type=1` and next row's `type=2`.
For ex : The result here is `2`. 
I don't know how to put `where` clause on `next row`.

Comment: The desired result here is 2 because there are 2 rows here whose type=1 and next row's type=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) to get the total:

```
select count(*) Total
from
(
  select type, 
    @row:=(case when @prev=1 and type=2 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as Seq,
    @prev:=type 
  from yourtable, (SELECT @row:=null, @prev:=null) r
  order by time, type
) src
where Seq = 'Y'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa76c/11)

Comment: It works but I really can't understand the creation of inner table src. Can you please explain it ?

Comment: @HappyMittal I used a subquery to apply to calculate the value of the user variables.  Once those are calculated, then you can get the `count` of them.

Comment: Ok...thanks. Can you please tell me one more thing. If I want to do same thing group by a third field ID i.e. for each ID, it tells such counts, then where should I put group by ?

Comment: @HappyMittal can you edit the sql fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa76c/11) with that additional field? I am not sure what you are referring to. Then post the link here

Comment: Actually I did it with an additional user-variable by using your design of user variables :). Thanks anyways. Here is modified sql fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcc9f/15)

Comment: @HappyMittal perfect, I am glad you figured it out. :)